# Branch Policy Exemption for Build Agent not working

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

As part of a TFS 2017 R2 CI build definition, I'm trying to merge commits from one branch to another. If you can imagine a bugfix in a test environment being added, then as part of the build def I run some git commands.

The branches have policies enabled, that essentially require pull requests for commits. In order for this flow to work, I will need to exempt the build agent from branch policies.

My build def is a single powershell script that runs "whoami" and then a git merge and then a git push. The Whoami returns a user:

```
domain\adminAccount
```

The admin account has the following permission properties:

- Collection Level: Member of a Service Account Group
- Team Project Level: The service account group is a member of the Build Administrators group
- Repository Level: The Build Administrators group has the "Exempt from Policy Enforcement" permission set to allow.
- Individual Level: If I add this user and trace their Exempt from policy enforcement permissions, they show "inherited allow". See image below.

[image: Permissions Trace]

However, when I try to push commits to a branch, I get the TFS error:

```
TF402455: Pushes to this branch are not permitted; you must use a pull request to update this branch.
```

If these account permissions are correct, and when I execute these scripts they show this account as being used, what am I missing? Is there some black box logic about what account is *actually* executing this that I need to exempt from policy enforcement?

Comment: What’s the account do you specified to log on as your build agent? If the account is not as domain\user and password  for login your TFS account, please change the account same as what you login TFS (as the example https://ibb.co/g57MC8) and restart the service and build again.

Comment: Hi Marina - this is a great tip, I'll be sharing the solution shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marina Liu - Let me know if I am saying anything incorrect, your answer may be helpful for someone else!

Some notes about the solution to the problem:

- The user that powershell scripts/build agents are executing as is a fairly useless piece of information. Instead, you want to use the command "git config user.name" to see what **git credentials** are being used.
- The reason is that regardless of what user is executing the build scripts, the build process will either use the user's git credentials (viewable in credential manager in the Ctrl Panel) **or** just the "nearest" git credentials. In our case, a user who was **also**  an admin on the Build Agent VM.
- My gut feeling is that branch policies are enforced in TFS by intercepting a git command, looking at the git credentials, and then trying to correlate that to an AD account, then checking for policy exemptions.
- Finally, Double check group membership for whatever account is executing the build processes on the agent, as this is ultimately what decides their ability to be exempted from branch policies. Even if you add that user in TFS and exempt them, if a group they belong to is even just "Not Set" for policy exclusion it could be blocking them!

Answer (score 1):

After the permission of Exempt from Policy Enforcement setbas Allowed for your own account, that means you already have the permission to push to the protected branch directly.

The only thing should be noticed is **the build agent should be log on as `domain\user`** as the user account you login TFS:

[image]

After changing the log on account, you should restart the agent service and re-build.